# Highmaps data from google sheets does not work

Tags: google-sheets, highcharts

I built a map with highmaps and stored the data in a google spreadsheet: [see fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/xtL4dbv1/3/)

This worked fine for a long time but since last week I get this error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

The same problem appears with highcharts. I guess google has changed something. In another case I get a CORS error.

I could switch to csv

```
csvURL: 'https://medien.lb.madsack.de/rnd/jchrist/electionsusa.csv',
```

But maybe there is a way to make the transfer from google sheets work again?

Comment: This is a known issue:
https://support.google.com/docs/thread/121088347

Comment: In Highcharts I only add the spreadsheet key. I Don´t know how to solve this.